# How to keep JasperReports report in a queue before send to the printer

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

I need to keep reports in a queue before they print. 
I use following code, but their some files did not go to printer queue.

```
  public void print() throws JRException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);

    PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();

    JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();

    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput("build/reports/PrintServiceReport.jrprint"));
    SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration();
    configuration.setPrintRequestAttributeSet(printRequestAttributeSet);
    configuration.setPrintServiceAttributeSet(printServiceAttributeSet);
    configuration.setDisplayPageDialog(false);
    configuration.setDisplayPrintDialog(true);
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();

    System.err.println("Printing time : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
  }
```

Report are sent to the network printers. Can anybody tell me why some report are not sent to printer when I print large number of reports. If it is better to keep queue for those reports and how to do that. My application is *Java* Swing.

Comment: Are threading the print process in anyway?

Comment: No theards are not used. overide exisiting report and send it to printer.